# Create a function to output a category hierarchy into a select drop down form input by passing the $categories array to the function

Tags: php

Create a function to output a category hierarchy into a select drop down form input by passing the `$categories` array to the function.

The given set array of data:

```
    $categories = array(
    1 => array(‘id’ => 5,‘name’ => ‘Fruits’,‘sort’ => 0,‘parent’ => 0),
    2 => array(‘id’ => 6, ‘name’ => ‘Donuts’,‘sort’ => 1,‘parent’ => 7),
    3 => array(‘id’ => 7, ‘name’ => ‘Hard Candy’,‘sort’ => 0,‘parent’ => 11),
    4 => array(‘id’ => 8, ‘name’ => ‘Pears’,‘sort’ => 3,‘parent’ => 1),
    5 => array(‘id’ => 9, ‘name’ => ‘Apples’,‘sort’ => 1,‘parent’ =>1),
    6 => array(‘id’ => 18, ‘name’ => ‘Oranges’,‘sort’ => 4,‘parent’ => 1),
    7 => array(‘id’ => 19, ‘name’ => ‘Sweets’,‘sort’ => 2,‘parent’ => 0),
    8 => array(‘id’ => 20, ‘name’ => ‘Red Delicious’,‘sort’ => 5,‘parent’ => 5),
    9 => array(‘id’ => 21, ‘name’ => ‘Granny Smith Apples’,‘sort’ => 8,‘parent’ => 5),
    10 => array(‘id’ => 10, ‘name’ => ‘Gummy Bears’,‘sort’ =>5,‘parent’ => 7),
    11 => array(‘id’ => 11, ‘name’ => ‘Candy’,‘sort’ => 8,‘parent’ => 7),
    12 => array(‘id’ => 12, ‘name’ => ‘Vegetables’,‘sort’ => 3,‘parent’ => 0),
    12 => array(‘id’ => 13, ‘name’ => ‘Yellow’,‘sort’ => 2,‘parent’ => 16),
    14 => array(‘id’ => 14, ‘name’ => ‘Grean Beans’,‘sort’ => 11,‘parent’ => 12),
    15 => array(‘id’ => 15, ‘name’ => ‘Broccoli’,‘sort’ => 10,‘parent’ =>12),
    16 => array(‘id’ => 16, ‘name’ => ‘Corn’,‘sort’ => 14,‘parent’ => 12),
    17 => array(‘id’ => 17, ‘name’ => ‘White’,‘sort’ => 1,‘parent’ => 16)
    );
```

**Note: Use recursive function if can.**

Output should like this:

```html
<select>
     <option>Fruits</option>
     <option>-Apples</option>
     <option>--Red Delicious Apples</option>
     <option>--Granny Smith Apples</option>
     <option>-Pears</option>
     <option>-Organges</option>
     <option>Sweets</option>
     <option>-Donuts</option>
     <option>-Gummy Bears</option>
     <option>-Candy</option>
     <option>--Hard Candy</option>
     <option>Vegetables</option>
     <option>-Broccoli</option>
     <option>-Grean Beans</option>
     <option>-Corn</option>
     <option>--White</option>
     <option>--Yellow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How can we relate the 'Apple' to the 'Fruits' without having the id of it as parent for Apple?

Comment: Show us what have you try, show us your effort. read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i try but its not working and its so far with the results. i don't know how to code it. that's why i ask for a help. it is so complicated on me.

Comment: if you saw ang 0 in the parent_id. it is the parent of all.

Comment: If you give the code from which you get this array at least we can try to find any solution

Comment: thats array is already given i don't know where they get it. just a sample. base on my understanding the main array are the basis for the parent. but i don't know how to sort it based on the parent and sort.

Comment: What this questions is "Help me with my homework because I didn't pay attention in class and now have no clue where to start"

Comment: this code is working the problem is the sorting of the child. anybody can help about this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the drop down of the products based on the category. But i couldn't do with the sorting order

```
<?php
function array_msort($array, $cols)
{
    $colarr = array();
    foreach ($cols as $col => $order) {
        $colarr[$col] = array();
        foreach ($array as $k => $row) { $colarr[$col]['_'.$k] = strtolower($row[$col]); }
    }
    $eval = 'array_multisort(';
    foreach ($cols as $col => $order) {
        $eval .= '$colarr[\''.$col.'\'],'.$order.',';
    }
    $eval = substr($eval,0,-1).');';
    eval($eval);
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($colarr as $col => $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
            $k = substr($k,1);
            if (!isset($ret[$k])) $ret[$k] = $array[$k];
            $ret[$k][$col] = $array[$k][$col];
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

$categories = array(
1 => array('id' => 5,'name' => 'Fruits','sort' => 0,'parent' => 0),
2 => array('id' => 6, 'name' => 'Donuts','sort' => 1,'parent' => 7),
3 => array('id' => 7, 'name' => 'Hard Candy','sort' => 0,'parent' => 11),
4 => array('id' => 8, 'name' => 'Pears','sort' => 3,'parent' => 1),
5 => array('id' => 9, 'name' => 'Apples','sort' => 1,'parent' =>1),
6 => array('id' => 18, 'name' => 'Oranges','sort' => 4,'parent' => 1),
7 => array('id' => 19, 'name' => 'Sweets','sort' => 2,'parent' => 0),
8 => array('id' => 20, 'name' => 'Red Delicious','sort' => 5,'parent' => 5),
9 => array('id' => 21, 'name' => 'Granny Smith Apples','sort' => 8,'parent' => 5),
10 => array('id' => 10, 'name' => 'Gummy Bears','sort' =>5,'parent' => 7),
11 => array('id' => 11, 'name' => 'Candy','sort' => 8,'parent' => 7),
12 => array('id' => 12, 'name' => 'Vegetables','sort' => 3,'parent' => 0),
13 => array('id' => 13, 'name' => 'Yellow','sort' => 2,'parent' => 16),
14 => array('id' => 14, 'name' => 'Grean Beans','sort' => 11,'parent' => 12),
15 => array('id' => 15, 'name' => 'Broccoli','sort' => 10,'parent' =>12),
16 => array('id' => 16, 'name' => 'Corn','sort' => 14,'parent' => 12),
17 => array('id' => 17, 'name' => 'White','sort' => 1,'parent' => 16));


$arr2 = array_msort($categories, array('parent'=>SORT_ASC, 'sort'=>SORT_ASC));

for($i=count($arr2);$i>=1;$i--)
{
  if($arr2[$i])
  {
    $cnt=0;
    for($j=count($arr2);$j>=1;$j--)
    {    
      if($arr2[$j] && $arr2[$j]['parent']==$i)
      {
        $arr2[$i]['child'][$cnt]['key'] = $arr2[$j]['id'];
        $arr2[$i]['child'][$cnt] = $arr2[$j];
          $arr2[$j] = '';
        $cnt++;
      }          
    }  
  }  
}

$res = array();
$n =0;
$res_arr = array_filter($arr2);

for($i=1;$i<=count($arr2);$i++)
{
  if($arr2[$i]!='')
  {
    $res[$n] = $arr2[$i];
    $n++;
  }
}

$res_arr = array_filter($arr2);
$str = '';
function fntest($arr, $str, $level='')
{  
  for($i=0;$i<=count($arr);$i++)
  {
    if(isset($arr[$i]))
    {
      echo '<option>'.$level.$arr[$i]['name'].'</option>';
      if(isset($arr[$i]) && is_array($arr[$i]) && array_key_exists('child', $arr[$i]))
      {
        $level1 = $level.'-';
        fntest($arr[$i]['child'], $str,$level1);
      }
    }    
  }
  return $str;
}

echo '<select>';
fntest($res, $str,''); 
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: don't follow exactly same on the output i need. just select what is the best option of that.

Comment: Yeah, it's fine but there is one left that you miss. you have to sort it also the child of the parent based on the sort value.

Comment: I already mentioned in the result itself the sorting is not working. It is too difficult to get the result from such a clumsy array format

Comment: yeah, I know. The array was so complicated and in-proper form of array.

Comment: some body can help me to sort this the child? this is working already. sorting is the only problem.